# docker tomcat не работает при смене порта

Tags: docker, tomcat

2 контейнера томкэт + БД.

Если заполняю docker-compose так, то все ок, работает через локалхост:

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  postgres:
    build: services/postgre
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password

  myapp:
    build: services/myapp
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
```

Если же меняю порт 8080:8080 на, например, 8080:8085, то не удается войти. Что нужно прописать, чтобы заработал другой порт томкэта внутри докера?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь сослаться на порт, на котором в контейнере не запущен никакой сервис, поэтому вам выдает ошибку. Если Вы хотите получить доступ к сервису по другому порту, то нужно менять первую цифру, т.е. правильно будет 8085:8080